# Akka-Stream: How to handle stream exception gracefully

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am working with streaming application where I received following exceptions:

1. ParsingException
2. FramingException
3. StreamTcpException

I have written Supervision.Decider but it doesn't catch all types of exception.

My questions are:

> 1. Why Supervision.Decider doesn't catch exception, it catches high level exception only
> 2. What is the generic way to catch all exceptions
> 3. Can I restart/resume stream within Future[Done].onComplete Failure

Comment: You may have a look to this : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/stream/stream-error.html#delayed-restarts-with-a-backoff-stage